# My sports program

Tags: cipher, sports

**This is my daily sports program:**

**First exercise:**

> 1) *Stand up*
>   2)  **Got on your knees**
>   3)  **Keep both arms on your body**
>   4)  Pause
>   5)  *Lean your body slightly to the left*

**Second exercise:**

> 1)  **Turn in a circle**
>   2)  Imagine there is a sweetness to your left, laying on the floor
>   3)  Point to it
>   4)  *Turn in a circle*

**Third exercise:**

> 1)  Stand up
>   2)  *Strech out your arms*
>   3)  *Put the right arm close to the body*
>   4)  **Move your head forward**

**Question:**

> **Try to find the hidden code**. 
>   Good luck!
>   And happy sweating ;-)

**Hint 1:**

> Don't be lazy

**Hint 2:**

> A mirror or a second person could help you.

**Hint 3:**

> The order of each step is very important ! It is connected with the front

Answer (score 2):

If we get up and try these gestures, these actions may look like:

First Exercise:

> 1) Stand up: `I` or `l`,
> 2) Got on your knees: ?
> 3) Keep both arms on your body: `X`
> 4) Pause: a space ?
> 5) Lean your body slightly to the left: `r`?

Second Exercise:

> 1) Turn in a circle: `O`
> 2) Imagine there is a sweetness to your left, laying on the floor: ?
> 3) Point to it: ?
> 4) Turn in a circle: `O`

Note that there are three kind of typefaces: bold, italics, and normal. This is almost 100% useful, but not sure how

Comment: These are very good observations... But no character is correct so far.